# Как изменить слаг (урл) на порядковый номер начиная с 0 в кастомной типе записи?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Создан условно кастомный тип записи - mods
Я хочу чтоб url имел тип site.com/mods/**XXXX** где XXXX это порядковый номер в категории ( не глобальный ID(%post_id%) ) , то есть начинается с 0 и идет дальше 1..2..3..

Comment: Мы не понимаем тебя братик, выражайся яснее.

Comment: Раз есть категории, то наверняка она будет не одна, как Вы планируете решать вопрос, когда разные записи будут иметь одинаковый "порядковый номер" в разных категориях?

Comment: И где а твоём урле рубрика? Как ВП должен понять из какой рубрики ты спрашиваешь "порядковый номер"? Ну и вообще  ВП не даст создать цифровой слаг.